# Why is padding_fifo_queue closed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My logic for the code is like that:

```
dataset = slim.dataset.Dataset(...)
provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset)
samples = tf.train.batch(provider.get(), batch_size=32, dynamic_pad=True, ...)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with slim.queues.QueueRunners(sess):
         result = sess.run(samples)
         print(result)
```

It sometimes works very well, but sometime print information

```
2017-09-24 20:42:34.519003: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu
\PY\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1192] Cancelled: FIFOQueue '_3_bat
ch/padding_fifo_queue' is closed.
     [[Node: batch/padding_fifo_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueueV2[Tcomponents=[
DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/
task:0/cpu:0"](batch/padding_fifo_queue, case/If_1/Merge/_119, trans    pose/_121, S
parseToDense_2)]]
2017-09-24 20:42:34.526003: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu
\PY\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1192] Cancelled: FIFOQueue '_3_bat
ch/padding_fifo_queue' is closed.
         [[Node: batch/padding_fifo_queue_enqueue = QueueEnqueueV2[Tcomponents=[
DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/
task:0/cpu:0"](batch/padding_fifo_queue, case/If_1/Merge/_119, transpose/_121, S
parseToDense_2)]]
```

I have checked `provider.get()` can work well, and I think I have followed the routine way to read data, so why will I get this information?

By the way, the shape of `tensor` which from `provider.get()` is unknown, so I use `dynamic_pad=True`, in other word, `tf.train.batch` will create a `padding_fifo_queue`.

### Update

I also have a test, it works well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim

x = tf.Variable([1,2,1,3])
x, _ = tf.unique(x)
print(x.shape)
y = tf.train.batch([x], 32, dynamic_pad=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    with slim.queues.QueueRunners(sess):
        _y = sess.run(y)
        print(_y.shape)
```

So I'm confused, what's wrong?

Comment: The queue being closed usually implies that either (i) you've reached the end of the data, or (ii) an error occurred when producing data that is enqueued in the queue. Since you seem to be getting flaky results, I'm guessing the problem is (ii). In that case, you should see more log messages above the ones you pasted in the question, including some that indicate that a preprocessing kernel has failed.

Comment: I think it is not  an error, because I can read data, but at the end of program, it will print these message, is it problem (i) as you mention? But I can't understand why it print these message.

Comment: Does it always reach the end of the program before printing these messages? In that case, you can safely ignore the messages, which are printed by TensorFlow as the input pipeline shuts down (and various intermediate `dequeue` operations are cancelled).

Comment: Yes, it  always reaches the end of the program before printing these messages. But sometimes it don't print these messages, like my update, it never print any message, which condition trigger will print these messages?